# 8 trials are necessary for 1 success, find the probability at any trial

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

### Question

Independent and identical trials of an experiment are performed until a success occurs. If, on average, it is found that 8 trials are necessary, find the probability that the experiment will be successful at any trial.

Consider the general case, on average, it is found that n trials are necessary, then, what will be the probability that the experiment will be successful at any trial?

### Answer

As this is a question involving number of trials up to the first success, it can be modelled by a geometric distribution.

$X \sim Geo(p)$, where p is "the probability that the experiment will be successful at any trial", and the expectation $E(X)=\frac 1p$.

But what does the expectation mean?

Wikipidea states "The expected value for the number of independent trials to get the first success, of a geometrically distributed random variable X is $\frac 1p$".

But I tried in this way (a wrong way):

$E(x)=8P(x)=1$

$P(x)=\frac18$

$P(x)={7 \choose 7}P(f)^7P(s)=\frac18$ where $P(s)$ is the anticipated answer.

$\frac18=P(f)^7(1-P(f))$

Why my working is wrong?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: **Hint:** What is a geometric distribution?  Given a geometric distribution with a parameter $p$, what was it's expected value?  Conversely, given a geometric distribution with expected value $n$, what is the value of the parameter $p$?

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability. Then the probability of getting the first success at the $n$-th trial is $(1-p)^{n-1}p$. The expected value of the number of trials until the first success would be the sum for all $n=0,1,...$ of $n$, the number of trials, times $(1-p)^{n-1}p$, the probability that the success was in the last one. So, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-p)^{n-1}p=\frac{1}{p}$. Therefore, if $8=1/p$, then $p=1/8$.

Comment: @Blue - probably better to start counting at  $n=1,2,\ldots$

Comment: It is not clear to me what your attempt at the end is... $E(x)=8P(x)=1$?  What is $E(x)$ here?  Surely not the average number of attempts until the first success, because according to you it is $1$ but according to the problem statement it is $8$.  You then continue on with some weird attempt at using a binomial distribution or something... mixing $P(x),P(f),P(s)$... wasn't $P(x)$ meant to be the probability of a particular trial as having been a success?  Why should $P(x)$ and $P(s)$ be different?

Comment: The correct approach is, as the wiki article suggests, very simply citing what you know about geometric distributions and performing the one line calculation $E[X] = \frac{1}{p}\implies p = \frac{1}{E[X]}$.  Done.  No additional lines needed.  No binomial coefficients used.